# Step through all children and remove all styles

Tags: jquery

I have a sharepoint site that is driving me crazy trying to remove all the junk code so I can apply my design. I am curious if jquery could strip out all css from all elements inside the containing div?

For example, how could I strip all css formatting from this html using jquery?

```
<div id="myID" > 
    <span class="myClass1">
        <span class="myClass2"></span> 
    </span> 
    <span class="myClass3">
        <ul class="myClass4" style="padding-left:100px;">
            <li>item</li>
        </ul>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Why not [use a CSS reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) instead?

Comment: .css() but I need a method to step through every element.

Comment: Like most other jQuery methods, `.css()` will apply to every selected element, and you _can_ select all elements: `$('*')`

Comment: All css including inline styles if possible. Maybe it would just have to remove all classes?

Comment: $('#s4-ribbonrow').css('*').removeClass(); is removeclass the thing to use?

Comment: @simple: no, removeClass is for classes. And wildcards won't work in .css()

Comment: Are you trying to remove element classes, the style attribute, or the CSS rules?

Comment: @MattBall: a CSS reset can't be used because it is only designed to remove the browsers default styling. As you can see in the example code posted, custom styling has been applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ([updated for the last time demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7L7va/3/)) (thanks to Fabrício for the pointer):

```
$('#myID [style]').removeAttr('style');
```

This will strip any inline style attributes of only child nodes of `<div id="myID">`, and leave everything else intact (removing the classes on those nodes can have other effects besides styling).  You could defined some CSS that only applies to the child nodes of `<div id="myID">` like a CSS reset.  That might look like this:

```
#myID * {
  border: thin red solid;
}
```

Comment: I like it. I always forget about *

Comment: The `*` is rather redundant here, it is implicit when you use a descendant selector without specifying a tag name - `$('#myID [style]')` should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

To strip all the css I think you would have to remove all the `style` `class` and `id` attributes.

This is my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QUYSu/)

This Javascript removes the style attribute and class

```
$("#myID *").removeAttr("style");
$("#myID *").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('#myID').find('*').attr('class', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me from the other answers was that not all children would be processed or an attribute `class` without `=classname` would remain.

This worked for me:

```
$("#myID *")                   // select all children of elements that containt id="myID"
  .each(function(){            // iterate through all children
  $(this).removeAttr("class"); // remove class attribute from each child
});
console.log($("#myID").html());
```